# Exibir data formatada em datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Na `datagridview` tem um campo data no formato `yyyyMMdd` e preciso exibir formatado na forma correta.

tentei isto:

```
dgvRequisicao.Columns["data"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
```

Mas ao invés de me mostrar a data formatada me mostra `dd/MM/yyyy`

Edit:

Populo o grid assim:

```
 BindingSource sbind = new BindingSource();
                sbind.DataSource = dt;
                dgv.DataSource = sbind;
```

Edit:

Aqui carrego o `datatable` do banco

```
  for (int i = 0; i < parametros.Length; i += 2)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parametros[i].ToString(), parametros[i + 1]);
            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
```

Obrigado

Comment: Poste o código que preenche a tua variável `dt`

Comment: retorna de um sql.. `executeNonQuery`

Comment: Tem como postar mais código pra facilitar a visualização do que estas dizendo?

Comment: Sim... coloquei o for que preenche os parametros e envia para o banco e o resultado retorna no `datatable`.. No `datagridview` configurei as colunas de acordo com as colunas do `select`

Comment: O unico jeito que consegui foi percorrendo esse `datatable` e colocou num auxiliar com os dados formatados.. Mesmo assim, muito obrigado!

Comment: Tenta pegar os exemplos que publiquei e adaptar pra sua realidade. Olha no meu Git, lá coloquei o código do que fiz pra tentar te ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

Como pude observar você está usando o `BindingSource`, então alterei o [exemplo](https://github.com/pablotdv/StackOverflow/tree/master/ExibirDataFormatadaDataGridView) para usar o `BindingSource`, ficando da seguinte forma

```
private void PessoaBindingSourceForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PessoaList list = new PessoaList();

            list.Add(new Pessoa() { Id = 1, DataHora = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), Nome = "Pablo" });
            list.Add(new Pessoa() { Id = 2, DataHora = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2), Nome = "Pablo" });
            list.Add(new Pessoa() { Id = 3, DataHora = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3), Nome = "Pablo" });
            list.Add(new Pessoa() { Id = 4, DataHora = DateTime.Now.AddDays(4), Nome = "Pablo" });

            BindingSource sbind = new BindingSource();
            sbind.DataSource = list;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = sbind;
            dataGridView1.Refresh();
        }

public class PessoaList : BindingList<Pessoa>
    {


    }
```

Uma alternativa que muito usei, é adicionar na sua coluna do `DataGridView` um `DefaultCellStyle`, onde nessa configuração você pode configurar o `Format`.

Adiciono alguns prints pra facilitar

[image: Edit Columns]

[image: CellStyle Builder]

[image: Format String Dialog]

Adicionei também ao git o [exemplo](https://github.com/pablotdv/StackOverflow/tree/master/ExibirDataFormatadaDataGridView)

Comment: legal... coloquei formatação `datetime` mas me mostra um monte de `exception` `System.Format.Exception`

Comment: o tipo de dado q está vinculando a tua coluna, é DateTime?

Comment: estou populando de um `datatable`

Comment: Vou fazer um exemplo aqui pra ver como fica

Comment: Editei a resposta adicionando o exemplo

Comment: Se puder, edite sua pergunte e adicione o código que popula o DataGridView

Comment: alterei a pergunta

Answer (score 0):

não faça esse tipo de manipulação pelo `datagridview`, traga a data formatada direto do banco,

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(seuCampoDatanaTabela,'%d/%m/%Y') AS AliasSeQuiserUsar FROM suaTabela
```